# Animation Progress Bar Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do I make an animation progress bar in three.js?
I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time.
I tried to use the html5 video player progress bar approach. But It seems it doesn't work for 3d animations.

```
var loader = new GLTFLoader()
loader.load( './resources/full_case/mymodel.glb', function ( gltf ) {
    gltf.scene.scale.set(0.1,0.1,0.1)
    gltf.scene.position.set(0,0,-150)
    gltf.scene.rotation.set(0, Math.PI * 2, 0)
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( gltf.scene );
    gltf.animations.forEach( ( clip ) => {
      let animation =  mixer.clipAction( clip );
        animation.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce)
        animation.clampWhenFinished = true;
        animation.timeScale = 1
          animation.play()
    } );

  } );
```

Comment: Maybe https://discourse.threejs.org/t/basic-loading-screen/2332 helps.

Comment: Mugen87 has a good answer, but check out mine if you need more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'd want to create a progress bar in HTML instead, and then display it on top of that scene.

HTML:

```html
<label for="loading">Progress bar:</label>
<progress id="loading" value="50" max="100">50%</progress>
```

You will notice that this won't be on top of the scene, rather, it would be pushing the scene lower.

In order to fix that, you need to create a class called `ui`, which you can user for *any* type of HTML that you want to display as user interface.

CSS:

```css
.ui {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then you should make sure to add the class to the progress bar.

```html
<progress class="ui" id="loading" value="50" max="100">50%</progress>
```

After that, you can use positioning css selectors to place the progress bar to the correct position, such as `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`, `margin`, `padding`, and more.